# Kotlin How to call method that passed as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

in javasript, if we know the name of the method, we can pass it as parameter and call it like this

```js
function foo(methodName){
 methodName()
}

function doSomething(){
 console.log("DO Something")
}
foo(doSomething)
```

I want to do something like this in kotlin, consider i have a class like this

```
Class DataModel{}
Class Foo (){
    fun build(data:DataModel,val onThis:AnyMethod){
        if(data.size>0){
            val param = somevalue
            onThis(param)
        }
    }
}
```

then in my Activity for example i have doThis method

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    //rest of code
    fun doThis(param:Int){
        Log.e("DO","THIS ${param}")
    }
}
```

in my OnCreateView i want to call something like this

```
val a= new Foo()
a.build(data, doThis)
```

To do this, how my Foo Class should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `val onThis:AnyMethod` to `onThis: (Int) -> Unit`, i.e. like this:

```
class Foo {
    fun build(data: DataModel, onThis: (Int) -> Unit) {
        if (data.size > 0) {
            val param = somevalue
            onThis(param)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do like this

```
// val mainActivity: MainActivity = ...

val a = Foo()
a.build(data, mainActivity::doThis)
```

or, if you run that code from within a member function of `MainActivity`:

```
val a = Foo()
a.build(data, ::doThis)
```

More information on how to pass around lambdas/functions/member functions can be found in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).

Comment: I have edited my question since i found new problem, what if the function needs parameter?

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto Then you change from `() -> Unit` to `(Int) -> Unit`.